# Inserting data in SQLite3 with AngularJS and PHP, I get [object Object] value

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, sqlite

I am making an app with AngularJS, PHP and SQLite3.

I am trying to make autocomplete to my app with angucomplete directive [from here](https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete)

This directive uses scope for storing autocomplete options:

```
$scope.countries = [
        {name: 'Afghanistan'},
        {name: 'Aland Islands'},
        {name: 'Albania'},
    ];
```

Every item is stored in an object of array. **The question is: when I insert data from input after selecting an item from autocomplete, instead of the name of country, I see the next value in database**:

```
[object Object]
```

That is, whatever word I select, I get the same value in my field - [object Object]. But other values are pushed in database properly.
The field where data is inserted has varchar data type. Data is pushed in SQLite with AJAX and PHP:

```
$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: urlInsert,
                data: thisData,
                headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            })
                .success(function(data) {
                    if(_recordAddedSuccessfully(data)) {
                        $scope.items.push({
                            id : data.item.id,
                            item : data.item.item,
                            qty : data.item.qty,
                            type : data.item.type,
                            type_name : data.item.type_name,
                            done : data.item.done
                        });
                        $scope.clear();
                    }
                })
```

After PHP processes data, it is encoded in json and inserted in database.

How to do so that data from `$scope.countries` is inserted properly instead of data I get `[object Object]` ?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? (The HTML.)